AWS AppSync Resolver: ddb.query vs Raw Operation Object in CDK
I'm working on an AWS AppSync project using CDK (Cloud Development Kit) to define my resolvers. I've come across two different approaches for writing DynamoDB query operations in my resolver functions, and I'm not sure which one is the best practice. Here are the two approaches:
Approach 1: Using ddb.query
import * as ddb from "@aws-appsync/utils/dynamodb";

export function request(ctx) {
    return ddb.query({
        // query parameters
    });
}

Approach 2: Using Operation Object
export function request(ctx) {
    return {
        operation: "Query",
        // other parameters
    };
}

I'm wondering:
Which approach is considered best practice when using CDK for AppSync?
Are there performance differences between these approaches?
How does each approach impact maintainability and readability?
Are there specific scenarios where one approach is clearly better than the other?
Some additional context:
I'm using TypeScript in my CDK project.
My resolvers are being deployed as part of an AppSync API in AWS.
I'm primarily working with DynamoDB as my data source.
Any insights or experiences with these approaches in a CDK context would be greatly appreciated!
When testing Approach 1 in the AWS Console, I get an error:
This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.

However, my queries still run. With Approach 2, I don't encounter any errors, and the queries work as expected.

Both the approaches to that you have mentioned to create JavaScript resolvers are correct.
The first approach is using an AppSync utility library @aws-appsync/utils. This library makes it very easy to write resolvers in TypeScript. You can read more about it's features here - AWS AppSync JavaScript runtime features for resolvers and functions.
In the second approach, you are manually constructing the request and response object which are expected by connected DataSource, where as in the first approach, you are using AppSync library to do that.
IMO, you should go with using AppSync Utility library (Approach 1) due to following reasons:

Easy to write new resolver or modify existing
No need to manually construct request and response objects
You get a lot other built-in modules and utilities support which are supported by APPSYNC_JS environment.

How to deploy the TypeScript resolvers with CDK
Refer the following documentation and videos to learn how to properly deploy the AppSync resolvers with AWS CDK.

Bundling, TypeScript, and source maps for the APPSYNC_JS runtime
Connect AppSync to DynamoDB with AWS CDK (JS resolvers) <--- Must Watch
EASILY use the AWS CDK to create an AppSync API

